# Can I define implicit conversion from std::function to std::shared_ptr<MyClass>?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, implicit-conversion

I have a class that works as a predicate to select value from list.

```
class Predicate {
public:
    // In this example, I am using QString as value type
    // this is not what happens in actual code, where more complex data is being validated
    virtual bool evaluate(const QString& val) const = 0;
};
```

Originally, I used lambda functions but this created lot of repetitive garbage code. So instead, I want to use predicate classes that use inheritance. For example:

```
class PredicateMaxLength: public RowPredicate {
public:
    PredicateMaxLength(const int max) : maxLength(max) {}
    virtual bool evaluate(const QString& val) const {return val.length()<maxLength;}
protected:
    const int maxLength;
};
```

To allow inheritance do it's deed, pointers are given rather than values:

```
class SomeDataObject {
    // Removes all values that satisfy the given predicate
    int removeValues(const std::shared_ptr<Predicate> pred);
}
```

Now we are surely stil going to use lambdas in cases where code would not be repetitive (eg. some special case). For this purpose, `PredicateLambda` has been created:

```
typedef std::function<bool(const QString& val)> StdPredicateLambda;
class PredicateLambda: public Predicate {
public:
    PredicateLambda(const StdPredicateLambda& lambda) : RowPredicate(), callback_(lambda) {}
    virtual bool evaluate(const QString& val) const override {return callback_(val);}
protected:
    const StdPredicateLambda callback_;
};
```

The nasty effect of this is that whenever lambda is used, it must be wrapped into `PredicateLambda` constructor:

```
myObject.deleteItems(std::make_shared<PredicateLambda>([]->bool{ ... lambda code ... }));
```

This is ugly. I have two options:

- for every function that accepts predicate, have an overload that does the conversion seen above. This duplicates number of methods in header file
- Have an implicit conversion from `std::function<bool(const QString& val)>` to `std::shared_ptr<Predicate>` which would execute this:

  ```
  std::shared_ptr<Predicate> magicImplicitConversion(const StdPredicateLambda& lambdaFn) {
      return std::make_shared<PredicateLambda>(lambdaFn);
  }
  ```

I came here to ask whether the second option is possible. If it is, does it carry any risk?

Comment: Why use a `shared_ptr` instead of a `const &`? In all cases, if you can you should make `removeValues` a templated method.

Comment: @Holt I need inheritance to work properly. When passed by value, objects seem to lose overloaded functions, which is called [object slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/274634/607407).

Comment: Yes, but a `const &` is not *pass by value*, it is *pass by reference*, and it works well with virtual function. But actually, you would have the same problem, see my answer for a real c++ solution.

Comment: Can you describe the "repetitive garbage code"?  Just in the implementation of `evaluate`?

Comment: @Holt Don't know how else to tell you, just wanted to say that it's a shame you deleted your answer. It wasn't exactly what I needed/wanted but someone else might find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use `template` to not expose code, you may use `std::function`:

```
class SomeDataObject {
    // Removes all values that satisfy the given predicate
    int removeValues(std::function<bool(const QString&)> pred);
};
```

and your predicate

```
class PredicateMaxLength {
public:
    explicit PredicateMaxLength(int max) : maxLength(max) {}
    bool operator ()(const QString& val) const {return val.length()<maxLength;}
protected:
    int maxLength;
};
```

So you can use either

```
SomeDataObject someDataObject;

someDataObject.removeValues(PredicateMaxLength(42));
someDataObject.removeValues([](const QString& s) { return s.size() < 42; });
```

Comment: Does any object with `()` operator implicitly cast to `std::funtion`? Will virtual methods still work? Currently, I have `()` in topmost `Predicate` class implemented.

Comment: Look at [std::function's constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function): Functor should be callable with given argument. For the virtual part, you have to pass the functor via `std::ref` to avoid the slicing.

Comment: @Jarod42 If you construct the predicate during the call (as you do), there is no slicing since the deduced type for `F` will be the type of the child directly.

Comment: I tried this but it refused to cast or construct the `std::function` from predicate: http://ideone.com/SpH8fI

Comment: @TomášZato `Predicate` does not have `operator()` implemented. See http://ideone.com/2b4YYf.

Comment: @Holt Thanks, that was awkward mistake. Now it actually seems to work: http://ideone.com/SpH8fI Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You want polymorphism, and you don't want to use template-style header lambdas.  And you want to be able to have a few default cases.

The right answer is to throw out your `Predicate` class.

Use `using Predicate = std::function<bool(const QString&)>;`.

Next, note that your `Predicate` sub-types are basically factories (the constructor is a factory) for `Predicate`s with some extra state.

For a `std::function`, such a factory is just a function returning a `Predicate`.

```
using Predicate = std::function<bool(const QString&)>;

Predicate PredicateMaxLength(int max) {
  return [max](QString const& str){ return val.length()<max; }
}
```

where the body of `PredicateMaxLength` goes in a cpp file.

If you have an insanely complicated set of state for your `Predicate`-derived class, simply give it an `operator()` and store it within a `std::function`.  (In the extremely rare case that you have some state you should store in a shared ptr, just store it in a shared ptr).

A `std::function<Signature>` is a regular type that is polymorphic.  It uses a technique known as type erasure to be both a value and polymorphic, but really you can call it magic.

It is the right type to use when you are passing around an object whose only job is to be invoked with some set of arguments and return some value.

---

To directly answer your question, no, you cannot define a conversion operator between a `std::function` and a `std::shared_ptr<yourtype>` without making your program ill formed, no diagnostic required.

Even if you could, a `std::function` is not a lambda, and a lambda is not a `std::function`.  So your conversion operator wouldn't work.